# Change default port when registering a new SQL 2000 server

Tags: sql-server, port, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to register an externally hosted SQL 2000 server through Enterprise Manager which isn't on the default port and I can't see anywhere to change it within Enterprise Manager.

So, the question is, how do I connect to the database if:

I.P. Address is 123.456.789 (example)

Port is 1334

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this via [Google](http://www.avianwaves.com/Blog/Default.aspx?id=25&t=Connecting-SQL-Server-Management-Studio):

> You add a comma and the port number to the end of the server name.
>
> So if you want to connect to MySqlServer.MyDomain.com on port 3821, you type...
>
> MySqlServer.MyDomain.com,3821

Answer (score 0):

Rob is correct - I have a SQL 2000 server running on the non-default port on a different instance name and the way I access it is like this:

> [ip or dns name]\[instance], [port]

example:

> my.server.com\MSSQLSERVER2, 12345

You don't need `\\[instance]` if you used the default sql server instance when you installed.